# How to make/use launcher?

Tags: docky

In ubuntu, I can run firefox with the command firefox in Terminal, or click the button in dock or panel.

How does this possible with ubuntu? I googled to find the name launcher, but I don't know exactly how does it work.

- Q1 : How to make launcher? If I make a GUI program, does that mean that I need to create launcher to start by clicking it?
- Q2 : Can I make a launcher for whatever program, even if it's not a GUI program?
- Q3 : How to link a launcher? How can make a link to a launcher in a Desktop to start a program?
- Q4 : The idea of launcher is unique to ubuntu? Or if I have one launcher, can I use it for other distributions?
- Q5 : Why some of the program pops up its icon in Docky (firefox for example), but some of the program doesn't (p4v for example) ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. If you right-click on a panel, you can "Add to panel" several things.... including a launcher. Similarly, you can right click the desktop and add a launcher. No, you don't have to create a launcher always. You can do it, or not.

Q2. Yes

Q3. Right clicking, as I said. Actually, launchers are text files... for instance, this is the content of my Desktop firefox launcher:

```
lubuntu2@PORTATIL:~/Escritorio$ cat Firefox.desktop 
  #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Terminal=false
  Icon[es_ES]=firefox
  Name[es_ES]=Firefox
  Exec=firefox
  Name=Firefox
  Icon=firefox
```

Q4. No, it's not ubuntu's exclusive. And I guess you're asking about the format, not the "idea", as you said, because Windows has its so-called "shortcuts" so that you can start an application .

Q5. You can add other apps to Docky, configuring Docky itself. In fact, that an application appears in Docky or not does not depend on the application itself, but on Docky.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can find additional information on what a launcher is and how to create it from [Help Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToAddaLauncher) and from the [GNOME Documentation](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.29/launchers.html.en).

Creating a custom launcher is easy. Right click anywhere on your desktop and select *Create Launcher* from the dropdown menu:

[image: DropdownDeskto]

The following window lets you insert the command to be executed when you click on the launcher. Type in the command as you would execute it from a terminal.

[image: LauncherCmd]

Last not least here you are also able to set the icon used by clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

I did some  experiments, and this is what I found.
I use an example of p4v (perforce client visualizer).

1. I needed to make a file p4v.desktop. I could easily do that with right click button.
2. For the icon, I just double click the icon in Properties, and set the icon.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
    
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Type=Application
    Terminal=false
    Icon[en_US]=p4_bigicon_bigger
    Exec=/opt/p4v-2010.1.276058/bin/p4v
    Name[en_US]=Perforce
    Name=Perforce
    Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/p4_bigicon_bigger.png
    smcho@ubuntu:~$
```

3. Then, I could drag and drop the launcher to anything (dock or panel).

   [image]