# Tiny program to register work hours

Tags: software-recommendation, time-management

I'm searching for a tiny application to register my working hours so when I come to work and power on my PC it registers my entrance and as I power off my PC it registers that I've left.

I know it's as simple as adding a note in gedit but I want it automated, phproject has a timer application where, as you start a task you push start and as you finish calculate time spent on it, and I'm searching for a similar small timer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [hamster-applet](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hamster-applet) [image: Install hamster-applet]

is an applet for Gnome panel That lets you keep track and monitor your activities, with the ability to display them in daily, weekly or monthly views.

```
sudo apt-get install hamster-applet
```

[image]

After you right click on an empty area of the panel, select the option **Add to Panel** and look for hamster-applet from the list of applets installed.

Comment: I've added a screenshot. You may want to explain in more detail why the questioner wants to choose this app :) (I think it's great)

Comment: I've added a detail description of this applications and how to install

Comment: dear hhlp thanks but i'm not newbie to linux and know to install and use it. and dear axl thanks to introduce me hamster i'll try it as soon as next morning

Answer (score 6):

Okay, now you've asked for a tiny app, and as any tiny app, this is missing features. But anyway. I've written one, very simple, that may do what you want.

[image: screenshot]

You can [**Download it here**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/560918/), save this file somewhere, right click it, go to *Properties* → *Permissions* and make it *Executable*, then double click to run it. You can also [create a launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23816/how-to-make-use-launcher) for it and [add it to your Applications menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16825/how-can-i-add-and-change-items-in-my-applications-menu).

- **Please note:** I can't promise you to support this, like a paid developer would do for you, but I hope it's helpful none the less. But if you want me to do some little adjustments, just post a comment.

---

<sup>Technical notes:
This will store all of the data in a file called `task_timer.json`, in the same directory the file is run from (probably your home directory). You can change this directory at the top of the file. If the app crashes or doesn't start properly, run it from the Terminal (use `cd path/to/file` and `./filename` to run it) and [provide](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) the output, so that I know what's wrong)</sup>

Comment: I had fun doing this, but I think Hamster Applet is better. :P

Comment: dear stefano thanks for your pretty python program,i love python but no exprience with json i'll try it as soon as possible, thanks for your assist

Answer (score 2):

You could do something *really* simple like run a script on login/logout that did something like this:

```
echo `date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S` - login >> ~/time.log
```

This would accumulate the list of timestamps into the text file 'time.log' in your home directory. If you just copy and paste that into a command prompt and press enter, it will create the file and add a timestamp to it.

You could make this more elaborate if you wanted, for example, by having the script poke a record into a database, or something.

Comment: thanks i were searching for a more friendly app so i can manage each month hours and etc but as an on hand solution it's a good idea to write my own script using what you said and add extra info to make it more friendly, thanks i try one and still wait if any one know about some friendly tiny app